# Mysql выбрать адреса которых небыло ранее по дате

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть таблица c email (`mail`) пользователей и временем добавления записи email в формате timestamp (`timepoint`).

Можно ли через select выбрать за текущий день только те адреса из `mail`, которые будут уникальными, т.е новыми и ранее не встречались. Получается видимо вложенный select, в котором сначало нужно выбрать за текущий день, а потом проверить их на уникальность.
Как в PHP это сделать я знаю, но можно ли решить вопрос на уровне mysql ?

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Нужно отобрать записи за текущую дату и проверить не было ли записей с таким же адресом, но более ранним временем

```
SELECT
  eml.`mail`
FROM
  emails eml
WHERE
  eml.`timepoint` >= CURRENT_DATE() AND
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      emails sub
    WHERE
      sub.`mail` = eml.`mail` AND
      sub.`timepoint` < eml.`timepoint`
  )
```

Данный запрос предполагает, что нет двух адресов с одинаковым значением `timepoint`. Если же это не верно, то строку

```
sub.`timepoint` < eml.`timepoint`
```

лучше заменить на

```
sub.`id` < eml.`id`
```

где `id` - уникальный автоинкрементный идентификатор. При условии, что при сортировке записей по полю `id` значения `timepoint` не убывают

Answer (score 1):

> выбрать за текущий день только те адреса из *mail*, которые будут уникальными, т.е новыми и ранее не встречались

**UPDATE:**

> @Akina - за сегодня может быть 2 записи с одинаковым email – Dima Kuzmin 13 секунд назад

```
SELECT email
FROM mail
GROUP BY email
HAVING DATE(MIN(timepoint)) = CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: `COUNT(*) = 1` а если адрес встречается более одного раза, то не выводить вообще

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Где такое написано? не вижу... это всего лишь мои домыслы, один из возможных вариантов интерпретации неоднозначности в вопросе.

Comment: Это у тебя так. А человек хотел `т.е новыми и ранее не встречались.` Т.е., как я понял, у него есть огромная лог-таблица, куда падают адреса, а он хочет вытащить все новые адреса, которые упали сегодня

Comment: *он хочет вытащить все новые адреса, которые упали сегодня* Это понятно, причём однозначно, и решается моим запросом. В том числе и в случае, когда имеется сегодня несколько записей с одним `email`, которого не было ранее. Но, возможно, требуются из всех только те, которые в количестве одной штуки (не дублируются) - формулировка вопроса не даёт понять, так или нет,- тогда надо раскомментировать дополнительное условие. Но может оказаться, что на поле `email` вообще наложено требование уникальности - тогда группировка не нужна, `MIN()` тоже, а `HAVING` превратить во `WHERE`.

Comment: Anton Shchyrov  - да верно. Новые за сегодня, но ранее не их небыло

Comment: @DimaKuzmin Не надо повторять то, что в вопросе ЕСТЬ. Лучше разъясните то, чего в нём НЕТ. Может ли за сегодня быть 2 записи с одинаковым `email`? А если нет - то потому что "не может", или потому что уникальный индекс?

Comment: @DimaKuzmin Мой ответ Вашу проблему не решает?

Comment: @Akina - за сегодня может быть 2 записи с одинаковым email

Comment: @DimaKuzmin Тогда мой запрос работает. Последние 2 строки с комментариями - удаляю. Запрос **Антона** - тоже работает.